# How to remove duplicates elements from array using php?

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

Hi this is my var_dump result. My problem is : If  my array contains more than once the same "name"(in my case "Test2"), then remove one of them. In my case all of the information from  [0] or [1]. Thx.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#24 (14) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(19) "Test2"
    ["taskid"]=>
    string(5) "11526"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#25 (14) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(19) "Test2"
    ["taskid"]=>
    string(5) "11526"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#26 (14) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(19) "Test1"
    ["taskid"]=>
    string(5) "11525"
  }
}
```

I want this result :

```
array(3) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#24 (14) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(19) "Test2"
        ["taskid"]=>
        string(5) "11526"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#26 (14) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(19) "Test1"
        ["taskid"]=>
        string(5) "11525"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you example dublicates not an arrays but objects, so you need to combine like this `array_map` and `array_unique`:

```
$arrayResult = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $inputArray)));
```

Or try

```
$arrayResult = array();
foreach ( $inputArray as $item ) {
    isset($arrayResult[$item->taskid]) or $arrayResult[$item->taskid] = $item;
}

var_dump($arrayResult);
```

Comment: you are right about objects, but your example gives the same result.

Comment: now it works. Can you explain me what did you done ? :D

Comment: You set an object into new array, but before you check if it exist in new array, if no it will be added, else it will not

Answer (score 0):

You can use  array_unique()  function